# Proguard won't include a library

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I have an android app which makes use of the following library:

```
implementation "com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries-core:7.1.0"
implementation "com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:7.1.0"
```

Which generates a list and UI about the 3rd party libraries used in my project. When I have `minifyEnabled false` it runs and does display the list of the 3rd party libraries. But when I have `minifyEnabled true`, it does not display it.

So I realised the issue could be with `proguard` and I checked the file, it has no sign of the library in there, so I added this line of code in `proguard`

```
-keep class com.mikepenz.aboutlibraries.** { *; }
```

But it still won't show the list of the 3rd party libraries as it does when `minifyEnabled` is `false`.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they mentioned in their [doc](https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries#proguard),
You should put these lines in your `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class **.R$* {
    public static final int define_*;
}
-keep class .R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you so much for your time and effort.